# Approximate image as summation of Gaussians

Tags: image-processing

I have an image that looks like the following. I want to approximate the image content as a summation of Gaussian functions, where the Gaussian means represent the most important points in the image and the covariance represent the degree of spread of the image. Is there any algorithm for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is, this is very specific.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to represent the individual blobs as (negative) Gaussian functions ?

Comment: So, when the number of points increase, `mean` increases and when points are denser, `variance` decreases?